# How to resolve path in gruntjs file?

Tags: templates, gruntjs

I have the following file structure:

```
application
|-  deploy
|----- Gruntfile.js
|-- package.json
|-- public
|----- js
|-- views
|----- templates
```

In my Gruntfile.js file I'm trying to compile jade templates likes the following:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

var templatizer = require('templatizer');

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-execute');

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    execute: {
        templatizer: {
            options: {
                templatesDir: 'need path for ../views/templates',       // ?
                outputFile: 'need path for ../public/js/templates.js'   // ?
            },

            call: function(grunt, options) {
                templatizer(options.templatesDir, options.outputFile);
                grunt.log.writeln('Templatizer done');
            }
        }
    }
});

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['execute:templatizer']);
```

};

I don't understand how could I resolve pathes for templatesDir and outputFile options?

Comment: I do not understand. Do you want to know how to put the path or how to get that?

Comment: Sorry my english is poor. I need to use there pathes in `templatesDir` and `outputFile` options

Comment: What happens if you put the files like the plugin documentation? https://github.com/dlmanning/grunt-templatizer Did you try it?

Comment: In this case I'll get an error because there files up one level

Comment: Really? I put my paths into the package.json file, and I write paths like "../../somefolder", and my gruntfiles works like a charm.

Comment: May you modify my code above to get it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be easier for you to use the [templatizer-plugin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-templatizer)

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-templatizer');

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    templatizer: {
      files: {
        'public/js/templates.js': ['views/templates/*'] // paths are relative from your gruntfile
      }
    }

  }
});

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['templatizer']);
```

whatever you do, it is almost always wrong to "misuse" the execute-plugin. search the [grunt-plugins](http://gruntjs.com/plugins), and if no plugin exists, create one [using grunt-init gruntplugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-gruntplugin). it is really easy.

**EDIT:**

i dont like the gruntfile to be in the deploy-dir. in my opinion it should always be in the root directory of your project. if you want to leave it in the deploy directory, you run it there right? then your config would look like this (remember: **paths are relative from your gruntfile!**):

```
templatizer: {
   files: {
     '../public/js/templates.js': ['../views/templates/*']
   }
}
```

Comment: you say `// paths are relative from your gruntfile` right? but it's wrong bacause gruntfile resides in deploy direcrory

Comment: see my edit. if you are not able to move your gruntfile, do it like this

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is it possible to make it more pretty? I mean what if I move gruntjs file I don't want to change all my paths.

Comment: how should that work? if your root always stays the same, you could do something using [path.resolve](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to), but why do that? just declare a BASE_GRUNT_FILE_PATH variable, and use it, so you just have to change 1 var if you move your gruntfile...